# Django - Adding an object to a model queryset without saving first

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a queryset generated by a model object filter that will be used to generate the options in a select on a form.

Value of the options will be Product.layout and text will be Product.description.

I need to add an extra option to the select with value=-1 and text='Not set'

I am trying to create an extra Product object with those values, and add it to the queryset without actually saving it to the Product table.
But the |= notation that combines querysets doesn't seem to work unless the Product record actually exists.

Is there any way of making this work? Or any way of adding a literal select at the filter stage?

My code is

```
 self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(layout=20).order_by('description')
 extraoption = Product(layout = -1)
 extraoption.description = 'Not set'
 self.fields['product'].queryset |= extraoption
```

The error is:

```
  File "<.......>\django\db\models\query.py", line 1216, in _merge_known_related_objects
    for field, objects in other._known_related_objects.items():
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute '_known_related_objects'
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't. `QuerySet`s are not collections, `QuerySet`s are representations of database queries. They may cache the result, but they are not lists.

Comment: So querysets can only exist for actual database content? Is there any way to do a literal select (like code = -1, description = 'Not set') within the filter?

Comment: @nickyc - use `annotate` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: But annotate just amends existing entries(?). I want to add a whole new object.